# How to target .NET framework to use on Windows 7 and 10 without install?

Tags: .net, wpf, windows, frameworks

I am developing a simple C# WPF application that I want to share to internal users. Many users do not have admin rights to install new versions of .NET.

I targeted .NET Framework 3.5 as it came with with Windows 7. Now some users are on Windows 10, and I see .NET Framework 4.6 comes as standard and 3.5 needs to be enabled for the application to run.

Is there any way to target multiple frameworks? Or build a launcher that will run the relevant Win 7 / Win 10 version?

Comment: Most important... how did you install this app without admin rights? In your installation you can add dependencies. .Net framework should be added there as well

Comment: You can let your .NET Framework 3.5 app run on .NET Framework 4.x by checking the previous thread. It is a simple `app.config` change.

Comment: @LexLi Thank you - your comment directed me to the solution via the duplicate thread (which I hadn't found).

Comment: @NawedNabiZada note "without install" in the title - copy/past of the executable and associated files.

Answer (score 0):

This is addressed by .NET Core as you can publish the runtime along with your application, which is called as self-contained deployment.

In .NET Core 3.0 (in preview at the time of writing), you will be able to build WPF apps as well and publish them to windows 7+ without requiring installations beyond required dependencies (Service Pack level).